# Как присвоить кнопке собственный идентификатор? PHP+SQL

Tags: php, sql

Есть форма поиска. Поиск выдает несколько результатов из таблицы авторов, так как могут быть однофамильцы. Рядом с каждым именем есть кнопка добавления автора в таблицу интересов пользователя. Как мне присвоить кнопке определенный идентификатор, чтобы при нажатии на нее в таблицу интересов добавлялся нужный id автора? У меня получается, что все кнопки хранят только последний идентификатор, так как использую mysqli_fetch_assoc().

Answer (score 0):

```
$qwery=SELECT id, name_autor FROM bazaDannix WHERE name_autor='параметр поиска';
```

после запроса авторов из бд вы получаете $id автора
пусть id будет передаваться в url

```
foreach ( $qwery as $rov)
{
    echo"<p>$rov[name_autor]<a href='scriptaddAvtor.php?id=$rov[id]'><button>Добавить автора</button></a></p>";

}
```

создайте файл scriptaddAvtor.php в котором напишите функцию которая будет брать через GET параметр указаный в url

и произведете корректное добавление автора в таблицу избранных